# What happens when Hinsberg derivative is added to acidic solution?

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines

> The Hinsberg test of $\ce{C5H14N2}$ compound produces a solid that is insoluble in 10% aq. $\ce{NaOH}.$ This solid derivative dissolves in 10% aq. $\ce{H2SO4}.$ Which of the following would best fit these facts?
>
> [image]

I think **b** or **d** is the answer.
The reason being it's insoluble in NaOH. That implies it should not contain 1 degree amine. Can anyone clarify any further?

Comment: Edit your question to explain why you think that and you will get answers.

Comment: Think about what base and acid solubility mean in the context of the question.

Answer (score 2):

" compound produces a solid" indicates that a reaction has occured.(hence no 3° amine group(according to this)). Further this is insoluble in base so there is a 2° amine group.

"This solid dissolves in acid" directly implies that there is a 3° amine group.

Hence there is both 2° amine group as well as 3° amine group in the compound.

Hence option b is the correct answer.

References:
1. Solomon and Fryle Hinsberg Test

Comment: You might edit this answer to give detail on what the Hinsburg test is - I had never heard of it and had to look it up.